# Not saving data to the excel using maatweb using laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

This is my first time using Maatweb/Excel in Laravel 7

The excel file is downloaded but it is empty.

I dont know what is wrong with this. Maybe some one can help me.

Here is my code AdsExport.php:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class AdsExport implements  WithHeadings
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */

    use Exportable;

    private $dateFrom;
    private $dateTo;

    public function __construct(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo)
    {
        $this->dateFrom = $dateFrom;
        $this->dateTo = $dateTo;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return ['View', 'Clicks', 'URL', 'Company Name', 'Ad Title'];
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return DB::table('ads_management')
             ->select(DB::raw('select COUNT(ad_views.id) as count_views from ad_views left join
             ads_management on ads_management.id = view_ads.ads_id where ad_views.created_by between ? and ?'), 
             DB::raw('select COUNT(ad_clicks.id) as count_clicks from ad_clicks left join
             ads_management on ads_management.id = view_clicks.ads_id where ad_clicks.created_by between ? and ?'), 'ad_link', 'company_name', 'title')
             ->setBindings([$this->dateFrom, $this->dateTo, $this->dateFrom, $this->dateTo])
             ->get();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance